# jQuery unexpected identifier using $(this) for mousemove

Tags: jquery, parallax

I'm trying to get a parallax effect on one element with:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#Parallax').mousemove(
            function(e){
            /* Work out mouse position */
            var offset = $(this).off­set();
            var xPos = e.pageX - off­set.left;
            var yPos = e.pageY - off­set.top;

            /* Get per­cent­age positions */
            var mou­s­eX­Per­cent = Math.round(xPos / $(this).width() * 100);
            var mou­seY­Per­cent = Math.round(yPos / $(this).height() * 100);

            /* Pos­i­tion Each Layer */
            $(this).children('img').each(
                    function(){
                            var diffX = $('#Parallax').width() - $(this).width();
                            var diffY = $('#Parallax').height() - $(this).height();

                            var myX = diffX * (mou­s­eX­Per­cent / 100);
                            var myY = diffY * (mou­seY­Per­cent / 100);
                            var cssObj = {
                                    'left': myX + 'px',
                                    'top': myY + 'px'
                            }
                            $(this).animate({left: myX, top: myY},{duration: 50, queue: false, easing: 'linear'});

                    }
            );

            }
    );
});
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

> Uncaught Syntax error: Unexpected Identifier for line 5 "var offset = $(this).offset();".

Am I missing something..?

Solved - there are hidden formatting issues. no problems with code

Comment: When I copy-paste your code there is a hidden char between `off` and `set` (shows as `off-set` in notepad). If this char is in your code too it might be the problem.

Comment: oh wow... I just spent ~2 hours staring at this wondering what was wrong and it was a hidden character. Haha oh my, thank you very much I'm getting more errors but I'm going to re-type all of this. I don't know how this happened, it's typed up in Sublime

Comment: I'm getting the same error on line 10 now. no hidden characters that I can see?

Comment: nevermind I just pasted it in terminal I see all kinds of formatting errors - thank you! that was a total life saver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad I helped Andrew.

My answer from the comments:

> When I copy-paste your code there is a hidden char between `off` and
>   `set` (shows as `off-set` in notepad). If this char is in your code
>   too it might be the problem.